# Use SSHTool to convert Putty Private Key to OpenSSH private key

Tags: java, ssh, putty, openssh

In my java project I create a SSH tunnel with a server.  The tunnel is authenticated currently using a putty private key and plink.  Does anybody know how to use the java [SSHTool](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshtools/) library to either convert a putty key to a openssh key or use SSHTool library to create a ssh tunnel using a putty key?  Thank you.

Comment: More details please. Are you using a library like http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/ ??

Comment: The link in the question takes you to the library that I am using, I tried using jsch but it doesn't seem to accept putty private keys to authenticate the ssh tunnel.  When my program starts it gets a putty private key in a soap message.  Currently I use plink to create a ssh tunnel to the server.  However, this program is going to be deployed on unix and windows boxes so I would like this side of the project to be platform independent.  According to the limited API documentation provided in the specified library, it can accept a wide range of keys.

Comment: I think the library with authenticate a ssh tunnel using a putty key...just not sure how

Answer (score 0):

Jsch only accepts opensh keys, not the format that putty creates the keys in. You would have to convert them. Use puttygen.exe to convert to openssh, then use the openssh keyfile in jsch.