# Converting ssh keys in java

Tags: java, jsch

Is there a java library to convert ssh2 keys to openssh keys. Much like the puttykeygen.exe app for windows.

Comment: Do you need an existing library, or could you incorporate a snippet of Java code into your project? It shouldn't be too hard. Also, can you provide links to specifications for your source and target file formats?

Comment: Possible Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986609/use-sshtool-to-convert-putty-private-key-to-openssh-private-key

Comment: I need an existing library, the two file formats are completely different, and I have no idea how they are each generated. All I know is puttygen converts between the two succesfully, however I need to do what puttygen does in java.

Comment: What license should your code have? If it is a compatible FOSS license, you might have a good look at how others (I mainly think about OpenSSH here) do this, and then port that to java.

Comment: Unfortunately my code is not FOSS compatible

Answer (score 0):

You can use PEMWriter to convert your private key to PEM format (.key) that will be accepted by most applications

The following example converts a key returned from KeyStore (JKS)

```
Key privateKey = KeyStore.getKey(privateKeyAlias, keyStorePassword);//get key from JKS
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
PEMWriter pemWriter = new PEMWriter(stringWriter);
pemWriter.writeObject(privateKey);
pemWriter.close();

byte[] privateKeyPEM = stringWriter.toString().getBytes();
```